# Swift and Firebase - Adding multiple nodes at a time with same Id

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to add multiple nodes at the same time the company is created. I can only add one node at a time. I will like the result in this image. I need to get the childByAutoId at the time of creation to use it as a ref to add the second node.
Then I just add the value like this.

```
"isActive": self.isActiveSwitch.isOn
```

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IILcl.jpg)

```
Database.database().reference().child(“Company”).childByAutoId.child("Profile").setValue([
 "Name": cName.text!,
 "Address": cAddress.text!,
 "City": cCity.text!,
 "State": cState.text!,
 "Zip": cZip.text!
])
```

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPlBR.jpg)

This is what I'm doing at this moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `childByAutoId` key this way and then use that latter to add `STATUS` node.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Company").childByAutoId
let key = ref.key
//Now set profile node
ref.child("Profile").setValue([
    "Name": cName.text!,
    "Address": cAddress.text!,
    "City": cCity.text!,
    "State": cState.text!,
    "Zip": cZip.text!
])
//later use this key to set Status node
Database.database().reference().child("Company").child(key).child("Status").setValue([
    "isActive": self.isActiveSwitch.isOn
])
```

**Note:** This is unnecessary if your requirement is to set both `Profile` and `Status` at same time then you can make it like this.

```
Database.database().reference().child("Company").childByAutoId.setValue([
    "Profile": [
        "Name": cName.text!,
        "Address": cAddress.text!,
        "City": cCity.text!,
        "State": cState.text!,
        "Zip": cZip.text!
    ],
    "Status":[
        "isActive": self.isActiveSwitch.isOn
    ]
])
```

Comment: Thank you, I was really over thinking this.

Comment: @R.Bruguera Welcome mate :)